# Calling Function from inside of dynamic loaded .js file not working properly

Tags: jquery, function

I'm loading .js & .css file dynamically when known class is exist in document.
when i call function from inside the loaded .js immediately, it's not work. but if i put an alert before calling, it's work perfect. why?

```
if ($(".pdp").length)
 { sysLoadScript("/sysdb/resource/myDatepicker.css");
   sysLoadScript("/sysdb/resource/myDatepicker.js");
   $(".pdp").each(function() 
    { ths=$(this);
     /* alert("this is work with alert but not without it"); */
    ths.myDatepicker({defVal:ths.attr("value"),fntSz:12}); }); }
```

Comment: Loading a script dynamically is asynchronous. You're trying to call the function before the script has been loaded. You need to use a callback function.

Comment: @Barmar, can u show me how? i try to load .js with $.ajax(... async:true). but it's not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your `sysLoadScript` function does, but this is how it's done with regular jQuery:

```
$.getScript('/sysdb/resource/myDatepicker.js', function() {
    $('.pdp').each(function() {
        var ths = $(this);
        ths.myDatepicker({
            defVal: ths.attr('value'),
            fntSz: 12
        });
    });
});
```

The second argument to `$.getScript()` is a callback function, which is run after the script is loaded.

Comment: can i use .getScript for .css file too?

Comment: No, you can't load CSS using AJAX. I think you need to add a `<link>` node to the DOM for that.

Comment: Don't try to post code in comments, it loses all the formatting and is hard to read. What's your question about that?

Comment: i try to do that in call back function. is it right or not?

Comment: I think that should work. Do you see the CSS when you inspect the DOM? Are the styles being applied? Javascript doesn't generally need to wait for the CSS to be loaded, it doesn't affect the script.

Comment: in fire bug it's not appended to head. when i use my function :sysLoadScript("/sysdb/resource/myDatepicker.css") it work nice. and DOM inspect show css is loaded. sysLoadScript is a pure javascript code for insert an <script> or <link> child into head tag.

Comment: Why don't you continue using `sysLoadScript` for the CSS, if you know it works?

Comment: i'm using it as i say. i try to load .css in callback function. but it's not work.

Comment: tnx alot. it's work, i am in a wrong path for .css file that i try to add. sorry.